# restart-computer with logs or result

Tags: powershell, restart

I need to restart 5 or 6 computers at the same time.
It works nice with the command `restart-computer`. But I want to add `-wait` to be sure each server has restarted.

So, of course, I can do something like this:

```
foreach ($VMs in $Servers){
    restart-computer $Servers -force -wait
    Write-Output "$vms has been rebooted"
}
```

I tried with `-asjob`, but I don't really understand how it works and how I can have a result. Also, it means I can't use `-wait` anymore.

Is there a way to export the result of `restart-computer` to a log or an array?
How can I know if one of the server could not restart, and will the script will continue to run if it's the case?

Comment: Please consider marking the answer that solved your issues as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Restart-Computer` gives no output of its own.
That said, you can simply do something like

```
# Creates string list to collect the logs
$RestartLog = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]@()

foreach ($VM in $VMList) {
    # restarts $VM, by force, waits for Powershell to be available, checks every 2 seconds for a total of 300 seconds(5minutes) 
    # if you do not set -Timeout, it will wait forever
    # if the computer doesn't answer before the Timeout is reached, the command goes on.
    Restart-Computer $VM -Force -Wait -For PowerShell -Timeout 300 -Delay 2 -WhatIf

    # Prepares Log line
    $RestartLine = 'Computer {0} has been restarted at {1}' -f $VM, (Get-Date)

    # add string to list
    $RestartLog.Add($RestartLine)

    # optional: write it to the screen
    Write-Host $RestartLine
}

# append list to log file
$RestartLog | Out-File -FilePath $FileLog -Append
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to use your script and adapt it to my needs.
I wanted to use a function, but it seems "Restart-computer" does'nt work with that...
Still, job is done. Thanks again.

Comment: Now I think about it, if you want the PCs being rebooted in PARALLEL, you can use `$VMList | Foreach-Object -Parallel { $_ ... } ` instead of `foreach ($VM in $VMList) { $VM ... }` (defaults to 4 at the same time). In that case you might want the loop to return a object or hashtable and sort them before converting them to string and sending them to the file, though, if you want\need them to be in order

Comment: Thanks Sirtao, I have no time to go further, and it works as it is now. But I will keep this in mind when I can have some time to improve my script

Answer (score 1):

If only working with `Windows PowerShell 5.1`, you can speed up the solution provided by @sirtao by using jobs.

In `PWSH 7.x` just use `Start-ThreadJob` instead to trim it down even further.
With big jobs, parallel piping as suggested by @sirtao is even better than `foreach`.

```
$VMList = 'Server1','Server2' #etc.
$FileLog = $ENV:ProgramData\Reboot.log #replace with your path
$RestartLog = @()

Get-Job | Remove-Job -Force # Remove any pending jobs from before

foreach ($VM in $VMList) {
  Start-Job {# Reboot each VM and check every 2 secs for 5 min using PowerShell
    Restart-Computer $Using:VM -Force -Wait -For PowerShell -Timeout 300 -Delay 2

    return 'Computer {0} has been restarted at {1}' -f $Using:VM, (Get-Date)
  }
}

foreach ($RebootJob in Get-Job) {# Wait for each VM to reboot and collect the result
  $Message = Receive-Job $RebootJob -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
  
  $RestartLog += $Message
  Write-Output $Message
}

$RestartLog | Out-File -FilePath $FileLog -Append
```

Note: I only use `+=` for increased code readability. It actually rebuilds the array completely each time which is a bad practice if working with large data sets.

See [Why should I avoid using the increase assignment operator (+=) to create a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60708578/why-should-i-avoid-using-the-increase-assignment-operator-to-create-a-colle)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I have to admit I'm not familiar with job yet, but this is definitly something I want to use. I will try to check this asap!